# Should we merge the tags [folk] and [folk-music]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have the tags [folk](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk) and [folk-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk-music). Both tags serve the same purpose, so it seems redundant to have both of them.

So, can we mark [folk-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk-music) as a synonym of [folk](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk)? As pointed out by @Bebs [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49298011#49298011), it is unnecessary to add "-music" in a tag, so it makes sense to have [folk](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk) as the main tag.

The stats look like this currently:

- 8 questions tagged solely with [folk](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk) (2 unanswered).
- 19 questions tagged solely with [folk-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk-music) (7 unanswered).
- 2 tagged with both (no unanswered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we should merge them.

Unfortunately, I can't do it, since I don't have the right for, but no doubt a mod will do.